# Unescape unicode-escapes, but not carriage returns and line feeds, in Python

Tags: python, utf-8

I have an ASCII-encoded JSON file with unicode-escapes (e.g., `\\u201cquotes\\u201d`) and newlines escaped within strings,  (e.g., `` `"foo\\r\\nbar" ``). Is there a simple way in Python to generate a utf-8 encoded file by un-escaping the unicode-escapes, but leaving the newline escapes intact?

Calling `decode('unicode-escape')` on the string will decode the unicode escapes (which is what I want) but it will also decode the carriage returns and newlines (which I don't want).

Comment: What do you mean by "decode the newlines"? They are stored as bytes `0x0A` and `0x0D`. `\r` and `\n` are just special string representations of these byte values.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It *could* be that the data contains some raw backslash + `n` characters.. Theoretically speaking that is. Not likely, but if so, then `.decode('unicode-escape')` would indeed try to interpret those.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Ah, the [JSON format](http://json.org/) allows for `\n` and `\r` and `\t`, etc. just like Python does. In fact, the format does not *allow* for `\x0a` or `\x0d` bytes, you are expected to encode those with a `\n` or `\r` combo.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But then it's a `"\\r\\n"`, not a `"\r\n"` string.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: exactly, but note that in JSON the unicode escapes are thus represented in Python as `'\\u201c'` as well, and the OP didn't double those slashes either.

Comment: They do contain raw backslashes, I've doubled them all for clarity.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Why is it unlikely that a JSON file contains raw backslash + n characters? Is there another way to represent a multiline string in a JSON field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is, use the right tool for the job and ask the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to decode the data to Python `unicode`; then encode the result to UTF-8:

```
import json

json.loads(input).encode('utf8')
```

Use `unicode-escape` only for actual Python string literals. JSON strings are not the same as Python strings, even though they may, at first glance, look very similar.

Short demo (take into account the python interactive interpreter echoes strings as literals):

```
>>> json.loads(r'"\u201cquotes\u201d"').encode('utf8')
'\xe2\x80\x9cquotes\xe2\x80\x9d'
>>> json.loads(r'"foo\r\nbar"').encode('utf8')
'foo\r\nbar'
```

Note that the JSON decoder decodes `\r` on `\n` just like a python literal would.

If you absolutely *have* to only process the `\uabcd` unicode literals in the JSON input but leave the rest intact, then you need to resort to a regular expression:

```
import re

codepoint = re.compile(r'(\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})')
def replace(match):
    return unichr(int(match.group(1)[2:], 16))

codepoint.sub(replace, text).encode('utf8')
```

which gives:

```
>>> codepoint.sub(replace, r'\u201cquotes\u201d').encode('utf8')
'\xe2\x80\x9cquotes\xe2\x80\x9d'
>>> codepoint.sub(replace, r'"foo\r\nbar"').encode('utf8')
'"foo\\r\\nbar"'
```