# Does python re (regex) have an alternative to \u unicode escape sequences?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

Python treats \uxxxx as a unicode character escape inside a string literal (e.g. u"\u2014" gets interpreted as Unicode character U+2014). But I just discovered (Python 2.7) that standard regex module doesn't treat \uxxxx as a unicode character. Example:

```
codepoint = 2014 # Say I got this dynamically from somewhere

test = u"This string ends with \u2014"
pattern = r"\u%s$" % codepoint
assert(pattern[-5:] == "2014$") # Ends with an escape sequence for U+2014
assert(re.search(pattern, test) != None) # Failure -- No match (bad)
assert(re.search(pattern, "u2014")!= None) # Success -- This matches (bad)
```

Obviously if you are able to specify your regex pattern as a string literal, then you can have the same effect as if the regex engine itself understood \uxxxx escapes:

```
test = u"This string ends with \u2014"
pattern = u"\u2014$"
assert(pattern[:-1] == u"\u2014") # Ends with actual unicode char U+2014
assert(re.search(pattern, test) != None)
```

But what if you need to construct your pattern dynamically?

Comment: You are creating a string `'\u%s` first, then interpolating the codepoint, and that is *not* interpreted as `\u....` first. That is *expected behaviour*. Use `u'%s' % unichr(codepoint)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`unichr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) to create unicode characters from a codepoint:

```
pattern = u"%s$" % unichr(codepoint)
```

Comment: This is a good solution to my example. But it also makes me realize that my example did not exemplify what I was really hoping to ask about. I was less concerned with injecting a single codepoint into a string of known form, and more concerned with how to deal with an unspecified number of \u escapes inside an arbitrary string. That's the direction I was trying to go in with my own answer -- though perhaps I should have used unichr as part of that.

Comment: @Chris: I covered replacing **just** `\uxxxx` escapes using a regular expression in [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367369/unescape-unicode-escapes-but-not-carriage-returns-and-line-feeds-in-python/14367455#14367455).

Comment: what does the `"%s$"` mean?

Comment: @alvas: `%s` is a placeholder for string interpolation; it is replaced by the output of the expression `unichr(codepoint)`. `$` is a regular expression meta character meaning 'match at the end of a line'.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is, rather than call re methods directly, wrap them in something that can understand \u escapes on their behalf. Something like this:

```
def my_re_search(pattern, s):
    return re.search(unicode_unescape(pattern), s)

def unicode_unescape(s):
        """
        Turn \uxxxx escapes into actual unicode characters
        """
        def unescape_one_match(matchObj):
                escape_seq = matchObj.group(0)
                return escape_seq.decode('unicode_escape')
        return re.sub(r"\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}", unescape_one_match, s)
```

Example of it working:

```
pat  = r"C:\\.*\u20ac" # U+20ac is the euro sign
>>> print pat
C:\\.*\u20ac

path = ur"C:\reports\twenty\u20acplan.txt"
>>> print path
C:\reports\twenty€plan.txt

# Underlying re.search method fails to find a match
>>> re.search(pat, path) != None
False

# Vs this:
>>> my_re_search(pat, path) != None
True
```

Thanks to [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python/4020824#4020824) for pointing out the decode("unicode_escape") idea.

But note that you can't just throw your whole pattern through decode("unicode_escape"). It will work some of the time (because most regex special characters don't change their meaning when you put a backslash in front), but it won't work in general. For example, here using decode("unicode_escape") alters the meaning of the regex:

```
pat = r"C:\\.*\u20ac" # U+20ac is the euro sign
>>> print pat
C:\\.*\u20ac # Asks for a literal backslash

pat_revised  = pat.decode("unicode_escape")
>>> print pat_revised
C:\.*€ # Asks for a literal period (without a backslash)
```