# Reading Regex Character Class Specifier from File

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am reading regular expression from a file and generally have had no problems until this one came along:

```
^X.{0,2}[\u2E80-\u9FFF]  # \u2E80-\u9FFF matches most Chinese and Japanese characters
```

The regex works fine when compiled internally:

```
p = re.compile(u'^X.{0,2}[\u2E80-\u9FFF]', re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
print p.search(u'XFlowers for you')  
>> none
print p.search(u'X桜桜桜桜')
>> <match object>
```

but the character range specifier is apparently garbled in the import process as it matches just about anything starting with X thereafter:

```
f = codecs.open(filename, "r", "utf-8")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
filePatterns = FileHelper.fileToList(ignoreFile)
patternList = [re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE) for x in ignorePatterns]

for name in [u'XFlowers for you', u'X桜桜桜桜']
    for pattern in patternList:
        print pattern.search(name):
```

This will match both strings.

Anyone know how to solve this on?
Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess, but i think the encoding on the file is wrong, try reading it as unicode or as ascii with the escape sequence

Comment: I thought the 'utf-8' specifier forced interpretation as unicode.  Is there another facet to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```py
>>> u'^X.{0,2}[\u2E80-\u9FFF]'
u'^X.{0,2}[\u2e80-\u9fff]'
```

vs

```py
>>> '^X.{0,2}[\u2E80-\u9FFF]'
'^X.{0,2}[\\u2E80-\\u9FFF]'
```

Notice the difference? The first example gives you a Unicode string with *actual Unicode characters* (that are only *displayed* as escape sequences), the second gives you a non-Unicode string with backslashes and a syntactically broken character class.

When you read the expression from file, you get the second variant. You need to turn this into a Unicode string - either by saving the file as Unicode and using actual Unicode characters, not Python escape sequences, or by keeping everything as it is and using the helper function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16541724/18771),

```py
import re

def unicode_unescape(s):
        """
        Turn \uxxxx escapes into actual unicode characters
        """
        def unescape_one_match(matchObj):
                escape_seq = matchObj.group(0)
                return escape_seq.decode('unicode_escape')
        return re.sub(r"\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}", unescape_one_match, s)
```

you can do

```py
>>> unicode_unescape('^X.{0,2}[\u2E80-\u9FFF]')
u'^X.{0,2}[\u2e80-\u9fff]'
```

or, in context:

```py
f = codecs.open(filename, "r", "utf-8")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
filePatterns = FileHelper.fileToList(ignoreFile)
patternList = [re.compile(unicode_unescape(x), re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE) for x in patternList]

for name in [u'XFlowers for you', u'X桜桜桜桜']
    for pattern in patternList:
        print pattern.search(name);
```

Comment: P.S.: Another variant, if you are bold enough to do it (not sure about the security implications), is `eval('u"' + pattern + '"')`.

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help. I kept finding postings saying that everything is AOK as Python does the right thing, which is usually the case. I just couldn't find the unescape means.

Comment: The Python interpreter parses Unicode string literals and turns `\uXXXX` references into actual Unicode characters in memory before the program runs. When you read a file, that step does not happen, naturally. Instead you simply get strings with backslashes in them, which of course is not what you want. That's also why using `eval()` works.

Answer (score -1):

If you need only english alphabets and numerals has to be matched, and not ascii or other characters try this regex - "\b^X[\u0000-\u007F]+\b"

It will match only "XFlowers for you"

Hope it will help.

Thanks.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I am trying to do.

Comment: If so you can use negation (carat) symbol. \b^X[^\u0000-\u007F]+\b

Comment: This is going down the wrong road, I'm pretty sure its a character/interpretation kind of thing